# Can't compile with gtk+ on codeblock ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks

So i'm really new at C and C++ (like.....i started a week ago).
I have this c++ script that i'm working on, I made an interface in gtk+ that work fairly well. Till now i used  window 10 but I had to do some multithreading (using pthread) and window is quite bad at handling those. So i decided to work on Ubuntu 16.
There begin the trouble, can't figure out how to make everything works....I'll try to be specific.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.0.4, mingw, openal and gtk+, to install everything i used :

```
sudo apt-get install gpp gcc g++ mingw-w64 codeblocks
sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev
sudo apt-get install libopenal-dev libalut-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev build essential
```

and if i understand it right it install the latest package of everything.
If i create an gtk+ project and test it with a simple code it works just fine....But when i try to test MY code i get an "fatal error: config.h file not found" in resample_defs.h...
And if I paste my GTK+ script that work earlier in place of my code i get the same error. So apparently gtk+ work with *.c but not with *.cpp
how do i fix that ?

Any help would be welcome at this point...

Comment: Is `resample_defs.h` from your project?

Comment: yes it is. I think it work with Openal, not sure tho

Comment: Where is it trying to import `config.h` from and how does the include statement look? Maybe there is a platform-specific path issue.

Comment: The fatal error is on the  `#include "config.h"` of the resample_defs.h file....i'll try to read the doc of libresample, I didn't thought about that.

Comment: Is such a file in the same directory with `resample_defs.h`?

Comment: there is no `config.h` anywhere in the project....and it worked fine on window before....i suppose it's fetching the config.h elsewhere. I  reinstall the package, no change. Can't find any problem OS relate for Libresample on the documentation either....i have no clues :/

Comment: Maybe `resample_defs.h` is not needed at all and was excluded from compilation in project settings. Try to remove it from the project and build again.

Comment: wtf ?! I deleted both #include, the resample_def.h and the libresample, rebuild and STILL get the same error message at the same line of resample_defs....and it's not called anywhere else in the script....

Comment: [EDIT: Ok the other include in the script are calling other .h in Libresample, one of them has to call resample_defs too that will crash on the same config.h....Still dont understand what the problem with it...]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. I feel stupid now.
Resample_defs.h WAS slignthly changed by de guy that created the script I work on.
There was an

```
#if !defined(WIN32) //which force the include of config.h
```

But since i'm now in Linux OS it doesn't work, so add an :
    `#ifdef __linux__`
well, that's that. Thank you very much for your help ! I can code now !